# Make git commit in submodule available to other local repos

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule used by a couple of other repositories, I'm making changes to code in the submod, and I want to make my changes available to both of my other local repositories *before* I push my submod changes to remote. The idea is that I want to be able to test the other two repos' code first, before I push the code that's shared between them.

If I just do a local Commit in the submod, how can I make the change available to my other local repos?
Is this even possible? Seems like it should be since all I'm trying to do is make local code available to local code.

Comment: A submodule is a repository, you can fetch/push from it directly to other repositories.

Comment: Good to know @phd but the question was HOW.

Comment: The answer by @Marco-Luzzara below is ok. Fetch/pull is the other way around: `cd second_local/git_submod && git pull ../../git_submod master`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. If you have the same submodule in 2 local folders, you can add a new `remote` in the one with changes, set to the path of the other repo. Suppose you have a `tree` like this:

```
├── git_local
│   ├── b
│   └── git_submod
│       └── a
├── git_submod
│   └── a
└── second_local
    ├── c
    └── git_submod
        └── a
```

where `git_local` and `second_local` contain `git_submod` as submodule. Currently you have update the submodule in `git_local`, but you want to "push" those changes in the submodule inside the `second_local`. Add a remote to that:

```
cd git_local/git_submod
git remote add testing_remote ../../second_local/git_submod/
git push testing_remote master
```

And the other local repo is updated too. Consider that you have to change the default configuration for `denyCurrentBranch` in order to do a push to a non-bare repo.

here the command to run in `second_local/git_submod`:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch "updateInstead"
```